# access denied :::7000 in nodejs event 498

Tags: node.js, express, permissions, localhost, port

I trying to listen on port using express:

```
const http=require('http');
const PORT_=process.env.PORT||7000;
const express=require('express');
const app=express();


app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.send("Hellow world"+PORT_);
    next();
});
app.listen(PORT_,(err)=>{
    err===true ? console.log(err):console.log('run on '+port_);
});
```

When I run the program on any port, get following error:

```
node:events:498
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: listen EACCES: permission denied :::7000
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1357:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  code: 'EACCES',
  errno: -4092,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 7000
```

The program works properly while I'm using http module.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because the port you are trying to listen on is already in use. Try to listen on a different Port other than the one you are using in your code.

Comment: On every port I get mentioned error

Answer (score 0):

One more case could be, in `.env` file you must be using semicolon (;) after declaring variable. While don't have to do that.

Example:-
In `.env` file:

```
PORT=5001; //this wrong
PORT=5001  //this is correct
```

Comment: Hi, while this maybe correct, has nothing to do with the original question.  Please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thank you